# Inaccessible windows account cannot logon

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, group-policy, appdata

After a computer repair and some unwanted changes by third party persons i got my primary user account is not listed in switch users screen. The default administrator account activated and its the only account that i can pick.

All of my previous accounts are listed in  control panel under (add or remove accounts) and from there, if i add new account to my computer, i can see this new account inside the switch user menu  but older ones remains not accessible.

My problem is not related to hidden fast user switch

I just need my older account because of program data's and all default directories and configurations etc...

If there is no way to access that account via administrator, then please tell me how can i rename the older user profile to retrieve my data's without any problem (same as cloning an existing user account)

Comment: If you press Ctrl-Alt-Del, can you then select Other User?  You should be able to .  If not, ask the person who did the repair.

Comment: @John absolutely not, im not thinking about new repair cause it has a new cost. I want do and learn this myself.

Comment: Try the suggestion in this Microsoft Article to adjust the user list shown on the logon screen:  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/how-to-make-windows-7-show-user-list-on-login/63cea659-f6a0-412d-a0b1-952a26c1df44

Comment: If the normal suggestions offered here do not help, ask the repair person to fix for free for you as they appear to have changed something

Answer (score 0):

The main reasons for this problem are:

- Windows Update upgrade to a new major Windows version
- Mixup of local and Microsoft accounts on the same computer
- Unwise changes in Group Policy or the registry.

I would suggest first to try and login to your old account by using as user name
the syntax of `.\account-name`. If this works, then the user account is still
there.

Use an administrator login to check in
*Computer Management > Local Users and Groups > Users*
if the accounts are still there. Double-click on them for Properties,
and check in the "Member Of" tab if they are members of the Users or Administrators
groups. If they are not, then adding to one of the groups will fix the problem.

If the problem is still there, try this:

- Enter the Group Policy Editor via *Start > Edit Group Policy*
- Navigate to *Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Logon*
- Double-click on "Enumerate local users on domain-joined computers" 
  and set it to "Enabled", then click OK.
- Check that "Hide entry points for Fast User Switching" is not enabled
  (it can be either enabled or not configured).
- Close the Local Group Policy Editor.
- Check that the users are now visible in the Switch Account menu and on the login page.

Another advice I have seen is to use `regedit` to navigate to
*HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System*
and ensure the item "dontdisplaylastusername" is set to `0`.